# Interval scheduling but with travelling and location

Tags: scheduling, dynamic-programming

[image]

So I have been thinking long and hard about this question and I think this might good old fashioned interval scheduling by finding the earliest deadline first.

Here's my approach,
Calculate the deadlines for each item (time it falls off the branch + the time it takes for the item to fall from the branch - the time it requires for me to travel there and catch it)

If the deadline is earlier than the current time then, I cant catch it.
However, in the ones that are reachable, I catch the earliest one. Then I again calculate the earliest deadlines for every item this time feeding in my new position.

However, this approach seems a little inefficient. Can someone point me toward a better one?

Answer (score 0):

After parsing and storing your input, you'll have some array of points in 2 dimensions (*x* and *t*) you should try to visit, no more than one x per t.  You need to find the optimal path through that array.

One approach would be to brute-force this.  You have (2**s*)^*t* possible paths - less, in fact, since you shouldn't move beyond 0 - *l*.  So for very small t, you could really find the optimal path - i.e. try every possible path, see how many things you can get to for each path, and return number of things from the best path.

However, if *t* gets big, then a brute-force approach would take some time (sub-exponential time).

You will need to find some approximation to this if you're going to code this up.  There are loads of algorithms with different trade-offs, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best-first_search .

Priority queues, as found in schedulers, could indeed be useful to this as you rightly state.